# Thunderbird: Quick search in the last N weeks

Tags: thunderbird

Is there a way to quickly search in all IMAP folders, but for mails of the last N weeks. For me I would like N to be 8.

I know that I can search the search dialog enter a from-date ... but that is too complicated for everyday use.

Do you know a solution?